# How to connect to my phone via adb on my pad

Tags: android, adb, unauthorized

My phone is Nexus 5, Android 4.4.3. And my pad is Nexus 7(2013), Android 4.3.3. Both rooted.

Now I want to connect to my nexus 5 via adb on Nexus7, but I failed.

I hava an otg cable and an USB cable, to link my phone and my pad together.

Both nexus 5 and nexus 7 have the adb in the /system/bin folder, so I'm sure that my adb can works. I install a terminal both in Nexus 5 and Nexus 7, and I'm sure that my adb server works well.

When I connect to my nexus 5 via adb on Nexus 7, it says, "device unauthorized". With command "adb connect *.*.*.*:xxxx", it says "offline". I don't know how to deal with it.

BTW, I know the service "udev" works in Linux while the service "vold" works in Android-Linux. In Linux, udev uses /etc/rule.d/....rules to recognize device. But vold doesn't work like that. Maybe this is the point.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi Ri, i'm facing the same problem "device unauthorized". are you able to solve it? thx.

Answer (score 1):

had similar situation. Here is what I did:

Try to check and uncheck the USB Debugging option in the device. (if not working, try to unplug/plug the USB)

At some point, the device should show up a messagebox to ask you if you authorize the computer. After you click yes, the device is then authorized and the connection is hooked.

[image]

Comment: I did this, but still there's no messagebox. I wonder whether the Nexus 7 has the driver or not. Thanks!!

Comment: I think, Nexus 7 has the driver, because I can see the device id of Nexus 5. But there's no access list in nexus 7, so "device unauthorized" appears....... I don't know if it is right or not...

Answer (score 0):

May be you were not installed Google USB drivers at android SDK Manager.

Please find the attached screen shot For your reference.

[image]

Comment: -,- The Android sdk can be installed in my Nexus 7?